# How to import Waypoints from my Package Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints, waypoint

Hi I need to use [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) (I learn about and download the WAYPOINTS  https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/zipball/latest) in my Website and I have the next issue:

In my JS folder I have the next Javascript files:

[image]

I import the scripts like this, FIRST ADD THE noframework.waypoints.min.js FILE AND THEN MY estufas.js FILE in the  tag of HTML5 code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/estufa.js"></script>
```

My HTML5 code is:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="firstCTA">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center"> 
            <img src="assets/imgs/clic-aqui.png" class="arrow-size"> 
                <h3 class="cta-here-text"><b>Da clic aquí</b></h3>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('firstCTA'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    
    alert("Main alert");
  }
});
```

THIS EXAMPLE give me the next error:

[image]

I think to I'm be bad, maybe I need import more files because the Main folder have all the next content:

[image]

thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Just add `jquery.waypoints.min.js` at the end of my code and IT WORKS. For more information see the next video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hPVpVtgle4&ab_channel=ThomasBradley